# Delete last 2 characters from every line in a text file

Tags: batch-file, text-files

How to create a batch file that deletes last two characters from every line of a txt file named list.txt

Answer (score 3):

```
@echo off &setlocal
(for /f "delims=" %%a in (list.txt) do (
    set "line=%%a"
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set "line=!line:~0,-2!"
    echo(!line!
    endlocal
))>list.txt.new
```

---

you can also use [sed for Windows](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm):

```
sed "s/..$//" list.txt>list.txt.new
```

Comment: Do you get a commission from sed? ;-)

Comment: @LS_dev I like it: it is reliable and widely used. :)

Answer (score 2):

Using a hybrid JScript/batch utility called [REPL.BAT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16735079/1012053)

```
type list.txt | repl ..$ "" >list.txt.new
```

If you want to over-write the original, then add this command

```
move /y list.txt.new list.txt >nul
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you take a substring of the string you read.

```
set str=politic
echo.%str%
set str=%str:~0,4%
echo.%str%
```

Since you cannot overwrite the file itself just make a copy of the original file. Write the new strings in there using the above method to change them. Then replace the old file with the new one. For details about that look at the following link
[Batch / Find And Edit Lines in TXT file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115508/batch-find-and-edit-lines-in-txt-file)

Answer (score 0):

I was just trying to do this but with a `cut` implementation.
I add it here in case someone also wants it.

```
rev list.txt | cut --complement  -c -2 | rev >> new_list.txt
```