# Find and replace line starts with specific value in text file via windows batch file

Tags: batch-file, text, replace

Even after deep Googeling I can't solve my problem.
Have a text file named test.txt. What I need is to change the line starts with the word "Root:" with other content - using batch file.

```
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion    
FINDSTR /B Root: test.txt 
::returns the correct line - works well
for /f %%i in ('FINDSTR /B Root: test.txt') do set root=%%i

echo %root%
::echos "Root:" - instead of the line content

FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN (test.txt) DO 
(set x=%%G
if !x!==%root% set x=Hello
echo !x! >> test.txt)
::The syntax of the command is incorrect.
```

How do i can do it?

**EDIT**:
Based on Magoo and on RobW at [Batch / Find And Edit Lines in TXT file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115508/batch-find-and-edit-lines-in-txt-file) - my problem solved as below:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in ('"FINDSTR /B Root: test.txt"') do set root=%%i
::root holds test.txt's line starts with "Root:"
echo %root%

SETLOCAL=ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
::iterate on test.txt's lines and compare to the root's value
        rename test.txt test.tmp
        for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (test.tmp) do (
            set foo=%%a
            echo !foo!
            echo %root%
            echo "%root%"
            if "!foo!"=="%root%" (set foo=hello)
            echo !foo! >> test.txt)                                       
    del test.tmp
```

Thanks!
Roni

Comment: The Syntax error is because the ( has to be on the same line as the DO.

Comment: In your first `for /F` loop, you need to provide the option `"delims="` to get the whole line; otherwise, `delims` defaults to _tab_ and _space_, so only the first token is returned...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q34900978.txt"

FINDSTR /B Root: "%filename1%" 
::returns the correct line - works well
FOR /f "tokens=*" %%i IN (
 'FINDSTR /B Root: "%filename1%"
') do set "root=%%i"

echo %root%
::echos "Root:" - instead of the line content

FOR /F "usebackqdelims=" %%G IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 if "%%G"=="%root%" (
  ECHO(x=Hello
 ) ELSE (
 ECHO(%%G
 )
)

GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

I used a file named `q34900978.txt` containing some dummy data for my testing.

The `tokens=*` option in the `for...%%i` (or `delims=`) assigns the entire line to "token 1" and thence to the metavariable `%%i`.

The default is to assign `token 1` but using [<kbd>Space</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd><kbd>,</kbd><kbd>;</kbd>] as separators, hence you get just the string `Root:` with your code (up to, but not including the default separators)

See

> for /?

from the prompt for documentation.

The syntax `SET "var=value"` (where value may be empty) is used to ensure that any stray trailing spaces are NOT included in the value assigned. `set /a` can safely be used "quoteless".

Next step is to process the file. Same story (but since I quote filenames and provide full paths, I need the `usebackq` option.

The entire line is assigned to `%%G` (note: except empty lines and lines which begin <kbd>;</kbd>

Then it's a simple `if` statement - if "the line content"=="target content". The quotes are required because quotes group "strings containing separators" into one string and `if` syntax is `if string` operator string2 (dothis) else (dothat)`

Note that the opening parenthesis must be on the same physical line as the **do** and the same goes for **if**. **else**, the preceding close-parenthesis and the succeeding open-parenthesis must all be on the same physical line with a space between them.

Note the use of `ECHO(` which will `echo` an empty line if `%%G` (in this case) has no value. The `(` is not counted as far as nesting is concerned.

(%%G here must have a value - but in the general case, `echo %var%` will yield `echo is on/off` if `var` is undefined, but `echo(%var%` will cleanly produce a new line).

Comment: Thanks!  Based on your solution and on RobW at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115508/batch-find-and-edit-lines-in-txt-file- my problem solved. I'll update my question.