# What is a simple way to replace text in a text file

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript

I want to create a small `vbs/bat` file that can fix a common bug with a program on it's installation.

Say the file `C:\Program Files (x86)\thirdparty\thirdparty.xml` contains the line:

> False connection: True

How can I change that to:

> False Connection: False

---

A modified version of the xml top lines
I cannot give the actual xml values as they are company controlled

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--Default XML file created for/by the Redacted Application.-->
<Redcated>
  <ApplicationConfiguration Environment="ProductionDB">
    <key name="redacted" value="redacted" />
    <key name="redacted" value="redacted" />
    <key name="False Connection" value="True" />
```

Value to be changed

```xml
<key name="False Connection" value="True" />
```

Comment: You may find this useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60034/how-can-you-find-and-replace-text-in-a-file-using-the-windows-command-line-envir

Comment: As I said in your previous question that you deleted, you could use a VBscript with XMLDOM.  But we would need to see the layout of the XML file regardless of what language we use to replace the text.

Comment: I  have added the layout

Comment: I would suggest once again that you remove the `batch-file` tag and stick to a scripting type which properly supports making alterations to unicode files. perhaps sticking with the vbscript method which you originally provided a script for and have now removed.

Comment: @compo I couldn't get it to work, the link is
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115508/batch-find-and-edit-lines-in-txt-file

Comment: Here is a great tutorial on creating, modify and writing to XML files with Vbscript from Microsoft. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.02.heyscriptingguy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use `Replace()` for such simple replacements, try the below VBScript code:

```vb
sPath = "C:\Program Files (x86)\thirdparty\thirdparty.xml"
sCharset = "UTF-8"

sContent = LoadTextFromFile(sPath, sCharset)
sContent = Replace(sContent, "<key name=""False Connection"" value=""True"" />", "<key name=""False Connection"" value=""False"" />")
SaveTextToFile sContent, sPath, sCharset

Function LoadTextFromFile(sPath, sCharset)
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 1 ' TypeBinary
        .Open
        .LoadFromFile sPath
        .Position = 0
        .Type = 2 ' adTypeText
        .Charset = sCharset
        LoadTextFromFile = .ReadText
        .Close
    End With
End Function

Sub SaveTextToFile(sContent, sPath, sCharset)
    With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        .Type = 2 ' adTypeText
        .Open
        .Charset = sCharset
        .WriteText sContent
        .Position = 0
        .Type = 1 ' TypeBinary
        .SaveToFile sPath, 2
        .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I thank you for your answer, however it does not seem to be doing anything.

Comment: although I resolved it in a seperate way using xcopy to copy a working copy of the xml to the location, I'll give you the Answer +