# modify the found text using batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, text, text-files, jrepl

Firstly, I am looking for something different from this:

- [Batch / Find And Edit Lines in TXT file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115508/batch-find-and-edit-lines-in-txt-file)

My purpose is modify the

`"fillColor="#242838"` with `fillColor="mycolor"`

However, the hex color in this statement can be anything like

`"fillColor="#221231"`or `"fillColor="#213123"`

So how can I find & edit the text using windows batch file.

**Edit**: I have tried  [JREPL.BAT](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6044) regular expression find/replace utility tool for this.

`jrepl "android:fillColor=(.*?)" "fillColor="mycolor" /x /f myfile.xml /o -`

However, escaping from `"`doesn't work in this line.

I have already tried `""`, `\"`, `^"` They don't help me to escape `"` character.

Comment: check this: http://dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044

Comment: Without an indication of the layout/format of your 'text' file, it would be foolhardy to provide a solution. Also providing a script which is different to what you want does not fulfill your obligation to provide **your** problematic code. Please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46181086/edit), including the missing required information.

Comment: @Mofi it doesn't same. hex color can be anything in this line so I need to use regex statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The task can be done with [JREPL.BAT](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) for example with using following command line:

```
jrepl.bat "(android:fillColor=\x22#)[0-9A-Fa-f]+" "$1FF0000" /f myfile.xml /o -
```

Explanation of search string:

`(`...`)` ... marking group. The string found by this group is back-referenced in the replace string with the expression `$1`.

`\x22` ... double quote character specified with its hexadecimal code value.

`[0-9A-Fa-f]+` ... find any hexadecimal digit one or more times.

All other characters in search expression are literal interpreted characters to find in file.

Explanation of replace string:

`$1` ... back-reference for the fixed string found by the marking group in search regular expression.

`FF0000` ... new color value which is here red (RGB).

It is necessary for this replace task to use a marking group as **JREPL.BAT** is using [jscript](/questions/tagged/jscript) which does not support look-behind to match just the color value to replace in right context.

This command line must be called with command **CALL** when used within a batch file:

```
call jrepl.bat "(android:fillColor=\x22#)[0-9A-Fa-f]+" "$1FF0000" /f myfile.xml /o -
```