# Batch file to delete text from txt file

Tags: batch-file

I have a text file that contains gmail contacts, after each address there's the name of the email address owner example : John(at)gmail(dot)com:John and some other emails like this : John(at)gmail(dot)com;John
each address is in a new line, I want to delete all names and keep just the addresses, so I don't have to do it manually each time. how can I do this in batch script. I want to delete everything after ":" or ";" in every line. Thanks

Comment: There's no easy way to do search and replace using batch commands directly, there are many third party tools made to help, but actually I prefer using VBSCRIPT directly in windows command prompt, check this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1115508/batch-find-and-edit-lines-in-txt-file

Comment: @Babak - Not only does batch have search and replace, but that doesn't even come into play here since this can be handled with a simple `for /f` loop using `:` as a delimiter.

Comment: It is interesting, so I guess you have an answer for our friend here, and I'll learn something new as well :)

Comment: this is well explained in the [documentation](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a simple one-liner:

```
(FOR /f "delims=:;" %%a IN (filename1) DO ECHO %%a)>filename2
```

where filename* are your filenames and `>` should be replaced by `>>` to append to filename2 rather than creating filename2 anew.